# Convergence of Schwartz kernels implies convergence of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $K$ be a smoothing operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e., it defines a map on all Sobolev spaces $K\colon H^r(\mathbb{R}^n) \to H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $r, s \in \mathbb{R}$. Now (a variation of) the Schwartz kernel theorem states that it is given by some smooth kernel $k \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n)$, i.e., $(Kf)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} k(x, y)f(y) dy$.

Now suppose we have kernels $k_n, k \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n)$ that do define smoothing operator $K_n$ and $K$ (since not every element of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n)$ defines a smoothing operator we have to assume this).

> What type of convergence $k_n \to k$ is needed, so that $K_n$ does converge to $K$?

Suppose I want $K_n \to K$ only as maps $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \to L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Does it suffice for this that $k_n$ converges uniformly to $k$?

Suppose I want $K_n \to K$ as maps $H^r(\mathbb{R}^n) \to H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $r, s \in \mathbb{R}$. Is it sufficient for this that $k_n \to k$ uniformly and also all their derivatives?

Comment: I posted this question now on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/117092

Comment: Do you want convergence as bounded linear operators in operator norm? In this case, first find conditions in order they are well defined, then try to compute the norm in the involved spaces.

Comment: Yes, operator norm is preferable. But I would also be glad about any information regarding convergence in the strong / weak operator topology.